# Erro no armazenamento de variavel

Tags: c

Sou iniciante e estou com uma dúvida, poderiam me ajudar a achar o erro desse código?
Quando eu insiro o valor do nos scanf ele altera para um outro.

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

/*Desenvolva um programa que faça a media de consulto de um veiculos após
vários reabastecimentos*/

int main(){

float km, litro, media, contador, vp, totlit, totkm;
contador=0;
media=0;
km=0;
litro=0;
vp=0;
totlit=0;
totkm=0;

printf("DIGITE -1 PARA ENCERRAR\n");
printf("DIGITE -2 PARA FINALIZAR A MEDIA\n\n\n\n");

printf("Quantas vezes foi ao posto abastecer?\n");
scanf("%d", &vp);

printf("%d\n", vp);

```
if(vp==-1){

    return 0;
}


    printf("%d\n", litro);
    printf("Quantos litros de gasolina foram utilizados\n");
    scanf("%d", &litro);

    printf("%d\n", litro);


    if(litro==-1){

    return 0;
}

    printf("Quantos kilometros foram rodados\n\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &km);

    if(km==-1){

    return 0;
}


    contador=contador+1;
    printf("%d", contador);

    while((litro>0) && (contador<vp)){

    printf("Quantos litros de gasolina foram utilizados\n");
    scanf("%d", &litro);

        if(litro==-1){

    return 0;
}


    printf("Quantos kilometros foram rodados\n");
    scanf("%d", &km);

      if(km==-1){

    return 0;
}


    contador=contador+1;

    totlit= totlit+litro;
    totkm= totkm+km;
    media= (totlit+totkm)/contador;

    if((km==-2) || (litro==-2)){

        contador=vp;

    }
```

}

```
if (litro==0){

    printf("Houve um erro ao digitar");

    return 0;
}

else {

    printf("Programa encerrado, resultados:\n");

}

    printf("Voce andou ao total %dkm\n", totkm);
    printf("Voce consumiu ao total %dlitros\n", totlit);
    printf("Sua media de consumo eh de %d", media);
```

return 0;

}

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Olá.
Você declarou as variáveis litro, km, contador, etc, como **float** e no scanf usou **%d** que é pra dígito/inteiro. ao invés de %d use %f que é pra formatação e variáveis do tipo float

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).